# Codeigniter 3.1.9 passing and validating array input not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm using CI 3.1.9 and in my HTML form below I create dynamic inputs from PHP with key and value like below:

```
<form action="<?= base_url();?>/process" method="post">
<?php
   foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
   // $invoice has values like 124-55441
?>
   <input type="text" name="amounts[<?= $invoice; ?>]">
<?php } ?>
   <input type="submit", value="submit">
</form>
```

Now in the config folder I have put a form_validation.php file with an array of validation rules as below:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/* Custom Validation Rules */
$config = array(
    'invoices' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'amounts[]',
            'rules' => 'trim|callback_checkAmountsToPay'
        )
    );
?>
```

In my controller Process.php I have placed the following code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Process extends CI_Controller {
   public function index(){
    if ($this->input->method(TRUE) === "POST") {
            if ($this->form_validation->run("invoices") == FALSE) {
                echo "Validation Failed";
            } else {
                $amounts = $this->input->post("amounts");
                var_dump($amounts);
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view('invoices');
            //Loading the form to view
        }
   }
   //Custom validation form 
   public function checkAmountsToPay($arrAmounts) {
        var_dump($arrAmounts);//Shows empty value
        $this->input->post("amounts"); //Shows all array sent by the form.
        die();
   }
}
?>
```

The checkAmountsToPay custom validation method always shows empty value for the post array of inputs "amounts[]" sent by my form however if I put $this->input->post("amounts"); it shows the whole array so why is the post parameters not sent to the custom validation function?

Thanks.

Comment: your form input should be like this  `<input type="text" name="amounts[]" value="<?= $invoice; ?>">`

Comment: When I do as you are suggested I still get string(0) ""  for the var_dump($arrAmounts)

Comment: check your browsers element tab to see the structure of your form , is there a value for `amounts[]`

Comment: What do you mean? It is when I submit the form that the array will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to use `arrays` in callbacks or validation rules, because of `Codeigniter's` form validation library limitation, you'll have to use strings.

**Try this:**

```
if ($this->input->method(TRUE) === 'POST') {
    $amounts = json_encode($this->input->post('amounts'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('amounts', 'Amounts', 'callback_checkAmountsToPay[' . $amounts . ']');
    if ($this->form_validation->run('invoices') == FALSE) {
        echo 'Validation Failed';
    } else {
        $amounts = $this->input->post('amounts');
        var_dump($amounts);
    }
} else {
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    //Loading the form to view
}
```

Get Like this :

```
public function checkAmountsToPay($value, $amounts) {  
    // $value returns first value of $_POST['amounts'][0]
    $amounts = json_decode($amounts);
    print_r($amounts);
}
```

Or simply use as your code in the callback function

```
$this->input->post('amounts');
```

Comment: I know that if I use $this->input->post('amounts'); I could get access to the array and do the rest of my validations however, I opened this topic to know why a custom validation method sends a post variable when it is a string and does not when it is an array of inputs values.

Comment: Codeigniter `callback` does not accept array, it returns you first value of array